# sum and Intersection of vector subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a vector space and suppose it has 3 subspaces $W_1$, $W_2$ and $W_3$. How to show the implication $$W_1\subseteq W_2\Rightarrow W_1+(W_2\cap W_3)=(W_1+W_2)\cap (W_1+W_3)?$$

Thanks

Comment: At the least you should post your own efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $x\in (W_1+W_2)\cap(W_1+W_3)$. Then
$x=a+b$ for $a\in W_1$ and $b\in W_2$, but also $x=c+d$, with $c\in W_1$ and $d\in W_3$.

Then $a+b=c+d$ which implies $d=a+b-c\in W_2$ (why?). Thus $d\in W_2\cap W_3$ and so $x=c+d\in W_1+(W_2\cap W_3)$.

Prove the other inclusion, where the hypothesis $W_1\subseteq W_2$ is not needed.

Comment: I thought about this question and I came to understanding I need to prove something close enough to be sure I understand it. So I found a very close claim and tried to prove it. the new claim would be: W1⊆W2⇒W2∩(W1+W3)=(W1∩W2)+(W2∩W3). To prove it I used the original claim (mentioned above). So I could replace (W2∩W3) by ((W1+W2)∩(W1+W3)-W1). It leads to W2∩(W1+W3)=(W1∩W2)+(W1+W2)∩(W1+W3)-W1. (W1∩W2) = W1. So it would be: W2∩(W1+W3)=(W1+W2)∩(W1+W3). And from here on - it's easier.. Have I done everything OK?

Answer (score 1):

I thought about this question and I came to understanding I need to prove something close enough to be sure I understand it.
So I found a very close claim and tried to prove it.
The new claim would be: W1⊆W2⇒W2∩(W1+W3)=(W1∩W2)+(W2∩W3).

To prove it I used the original claim (mentioned above).
So I could replace (W2∩W3) by ((W1+W2)∩(W1+W3)-W1).

It leads to W2∩(W1+W3)=(W1∩W2)+(W1+W2)∩(W1+W3)-W1. (W1∩W2) = W1.

So it would be: W2∩(W1+W3)=(W1+W2)∩(W1+W3).
 And from here on - it's easier.. Have I done everything OK?